# Como instalar Laravel em um servidor?

Tags: php, laravel, servidor, framework, instalador

No Wordpress, por exemplo utilizamos o ftp para o envio de arquivos. 
Porém, no Laravel é utilizado composer, e pelo o que parece ele é instalado localmente. 
Como eu faço para instalar em um endereço de web mesmo? 
Espero que faça sentido, e me perdoem pela pergunta tosca!

Obrigada, desde já.

Comment: Ele pode ser instalado normalmente em um servidor FTP, pois o composer é apenas um gerenciador de pacotes php. Ele n interfere em nada em uma aplicação em laravel.

Answer (score 1):

Creio que essa resposta nos leva ao famoso "depende"...

Depende do que?

Seu servidor é compartilhado ou dedicado?

## Em servidores Dedicados

Na empresa onde trabalho, utilizo um servidor dedicado.
Quando precisamos atualizar nossos sistemas feitos em Laravel, fazemos da seguinte forma:

- Usamos o `Git` para controle de versão.
- Fazemos um `git pull` na  pasta da aplicação quando há novas alterações.
- Instalamos o composer no servidor e rodamos o comando `composer update` quando é necessário para instalar as dependências. Se o sistema for novo, então rodamos `composer install`.

## Em Servidores Dedicados

Eu faria tudo o que acabei de citar acima. E, quando as minhas alterações estivessem concluídas, faria um `ftp` enviando todo o projeto para produção.

Lembrando que você deve fazer com que a sua aplicação aponte para a pasta `public/` do `Laravel`. Isso é fácil de configurar em servidores dedicados.

Nada impede de fazer um `FTP` em uma aplicação feita em Laravel, você só vai ter que saber como configurar corretamente  (principalmente em servidores compartilhados)